# $E(Xg(Y))=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} g(y)\nu(dy),$ where $\nu(B)=E(X\mathbb{1}_B(Y))$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, probability-theory

Let $X,Y$ be a random variable and a $d$-dimensional random vector respectively on a probability space. Show that for a continuous $g:\mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ 
$$E(Xg(Y))=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} g(y)\nu(dy),$$ where $\nu$ is the signed measure 
$\nu(B)=E(X\mathbb{1}_B(Y))$.

I started with $g=1_A$ for some measurable set $A$, then easily get the identity. 
Thus, for any simple function $g$, we have the identity. However, I do not know how to extend this identity for continuous functions $g$, since I can't use the monotone convergence theorem here. 
I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: First solve it for unsigned measures $\nu_+$ and $\nu_-$ prescribed by $\nu_+(B)=\mathbb EX_+1_B(Y)$ and $\nu_-(B)=\mathbb EX_-1_B(Y)$. Then for $\nu=\nu_+-\nu_-$.

Comment: @drhab So from your suggestion, I can get $EX_+ g(Y)= \int g(y)\nu_+(dy)$  for all measurable $g$ using the monotone convergence theorem, and then the same for $EX_- g(Y)$ and then the same for $\nu_-$. So adding all of them up I would have for all measurable (not just continuous) mappings $g$, $EXg(Y)= \int g(y)\nu(dy)$. Is this correct?

Comment: I haven't looked at it intensively (hence did not give a real answer) and of course you must be careful with $\pm\infty$. But yes, I think that is the route to go.